# How do I extract the last occurring string within a parentheses with a column string into another column using stringr?

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, stringr

I have a set of random text in column like this:

```
dplyr::tibble(text = c("I have a (brown) clock", "surrounded by (red) walls", "inside of a (blue) building with (dirty) windows",
                      "where (magical) things (unexpectedly) occur (spontaneously)"))

# A tibble: 4 x 1
  text                                                       
  <chr>                                                      
1 I have a (brown) clock                                     
2 surrounded by (red) walls                                  
3 inside of a (blue) building with (dirty) windows           
4 where (magical) things (unexpectedly) occur (spontaneously)
```

I'd like to extract the last occurring string within a parentheses into another column so that it looks like this:

```
dplyr::tibble(text = c("I have a (brown) clock", "surrounded by (red) walls", "inside of a (blue) building with (dirty) windows",
                          "where (magical) things (unexpectedly) occur (spontaneously)"),
                  extract = c("brown", "red", "dirty", "spontaneously"))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  text                                                        extract      
  <chr>                                                       <chr>        
1 I have a (brown) clock                                      brown        
2 surrounded by (red) walls                                   red          
3 inside of a (blue) building with (dirty) windows            dirty        
4 where (magical) things (unexpectedly) occur (spontaneously) spontaneously
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `stri_extract_last` from `stringi` and it should be fast.  Here, we do a regex lookaround to match the opening parenthesis (`(?<=\\()`) followed by one or more characters that are not a closing parentheses (`[^\\)]+`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(extract = stringi::stri_extract_last(text, regex = "(?<=\\()[^\\)]+"))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  text                                                        extract      
#  <chr>                                                       <chr>        
#1 I have a (brown) clock                                      brown        
#2 surrounded by (red) walls                                   red          
#3 inside of a (blue) building with (dirty) windows            dirty        
#4 where (magical) things (unexpectedly) occur (spontaneously) spontaneously
```